# Nodejs cannot find module './layer' using express

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, express

I'm using nodejs with express and request. When I run it locally (on windows), it works, but when I upload it to my server it doesn't. I'm using visual studio with gitbucket and I also selected that visual studio should publish the files in the node_modules directory. I'm using the newest version of express (`npm install express`).

I don't know what this message is about because there is no directory 'layer' (although it works locally).

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layer.js` is required by express here: https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js#L6

Make sure you're properly `npm install`ing on your remote server.

Comment: I don't understand why I should `npm install` on my server when I theoretically have all required files in my node_modules directory? Why is the error not occurring locally?

Comment: It's possible that it has something to do with the requirements of `express`.  You should at least try running `npm install`. Copying `node_modules` is a bit of an antipattern

Comment: `npm install` did nothing except a new line, `npm install express` gets a new error (not compatible with your version of node/npm: connect@2.11.0).. I hate programming

Comment: Sounds like you just need to update node & npm on your remote machine. Try that

Comment: Very odd. I would try deleting node_modules, making sure you have the latest version of those modules and then reinstalling them

Comment: Ok, thank you, works now. Updated with chris-lea repos and added express with npm install